# Excel - does data validation count as a cell style?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, data-validation

I have an Excel spreadsheet which serves as a data dump/transfer facility from an in-house application.
The spreadsheet also acts as a crude data-entry facility, as a modified spreadsheet can be imported back into the app. As such the spreadsheet is occasionally given to external users.

We have a couple of columns (say 3 and 7) where the cells have data validation applied. The thing is, the validation lists are not necessarily the same for every cell in the column. For example, the cell (R1,C3) might have allowable values of A,B,C; for the cell (R2,C3) it might be D,E,F; and so on.

What I have found is that once the spreadsheet gets sufficiently large, Excel complains when opening it.  The problem seems to be the cells with data validation.  I say this because

- if I use an older version of the dump (which applies validation to one less column), I don't get the errors;
- the only thing I'm losing when I allow Excel to "repair" the errors is the data validation.

According to [Microsoft's list of known limitations](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3#ID0EBABAAA=Excel_2007), I should only be able to have 10,000 drop-down filter lists.  I'm assuming that's the number of unique lists, because I'm able to have many more cells than that with filtering applied.

However, per the above linked document there is a limit of 64,000 cell styles.  And I know that performing validation on the additional column pushes the number of cells with validation over 64,000.  So my question is ... does data validation count as a cell style?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about that, but if you want you can download [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/djymu6ad72nfgoe/Utilities.bas?dl=0) VBA code that have a function called StyleKilller that you can use to clean all useless styles from you spreadsheet.